# In MongoDB, how do I update the value of a nested document using a function that operates on the current value?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to $trim the value of field within a nested document and for the life of me have not been able to figure out how to get it to work.

I want to run $trim on the `code` field of all documents so that both leading and trailing spaces are removed from the documents at-rest in MongoDB.

I'm using MongoDB 4.2.

My document structure is as follows:

```json
{
   "_id": "root_id",
   "products": [
      {
         "id": "p1",
         "code": "TRAILING "
      },
      {
         "id": "p2",
         "code": " LEADING"
      }
      {
         "id": "p3",
         "code": "CLEAN"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work the [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/#updates-with-aggregation-pipeline) for MongoDB version 4.2.

1. `$set` - Set `products` field value.

   1.1. `$map` - Iterate the `products` array and return a new array.

   1.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge current object (`$$this`) and object with `code` field from *1.1.1.1*.

   1.1.1.1. `$trim` - Trim `code` value.

And with `{ multi: true }` for updating multiple documents.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      products: {
        $map: {
          input: "$products",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                code: {
                  $trim: {
                    input: "$$this.code"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9knTsbuDp8h)

Comment: This solution is very neat and concise :)

Comment: Fantastic solution!  Thank you for the prompt response.